# Problema al conectarme desde .net a Oracle con EF

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odac

les explico un poco el problema de mi escenario, en mi maquina de desarrollo tengo instalado el ODAC 12 y puede desarrollar normal conexiones contra Oracle, en mi servidor de producción instale el mismo Oracle pero al intentar ejecutar mi aplicacion.exe me lanza la siguiente excepción:

> Mensaje:

```
The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.
```

> Pila

```
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
```

> InnerExepcion

```
   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString)
```

Bueno no se que pueda ser, ya que el mismo .exe si funciona en mi maquina y en el server no, descarte que es conexiona porque otra aplicación con la cadena de conexión (a la antigua);

```
oCon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=ORAOLEDB.ORACLE;OLE DB Services=3;User Id=xxx;Password=yyy;Data Source=zzzz");
```

si funciona normal, pero la que tengo con EF5 no me funciona.

Comment: lo que no mencionas es como mapeas EF usando oracle, usas Code First o es por medio de un edmx ?

Comment: lo que utilizo es edmx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede ser que la versión del cliente de Oracle que instalaste sea de 64 bits pero la aplicación esté corriendo en 32 bits o viceversa.

Si tu aplicación es una aplicación web en un servidor de 64 bits y tu cliente de Oracle instalado es de 32 bits puedes configurar el App Pool del IIS para ejecutar tu app en 32 bits.

Saludos.

Comment: El una aplicación winform, y en la compilaciía esta en ANY, no especificamente en x86 o x64

Comment: @RSillerico cambia la compilación a `x86` y `x64` y prueba de nuevo; luego actualiza tu pregunta con los resultados obtenidos.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendaria le desde una mirada a

[Entity Framework, LINQ and Model-First for the Oracle Database](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/EntityFrameworkOBE_2/EntityFrameworkOBE.html#)

alli crea un `edmx` para mapear la db Oracle con EF

Si te puedes conectar a Oracle desde el Server Explorer entonces podrias usar este en el wizard que crea el modelo de EF

Revisa la seccion `Creating an Entity Data Model using the Entity Data Model Wizard`

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos por sus sugerencias, bueno la que al final me sirvió mas fue la de Gustavo, compilado independientemente para x86 y x64, funciona la de x64, y como se hace para que un ANY funcione? pues en propiedades del proyecto, en la opción de compilación hay un checkbox que dice "preferentemente de 32 bits", deshabilitando esa opción también llega a funcionar la ANY. Saludos a todos y nuevamente muchas gracias.